# MySQL next and prev record issue

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I made this php script and i am tryin to make it to return next and previus row, but there is one problem when i input my id the script return different thing for example :

This is my DB

```
ID  String
1   Test 1
2   Test 2
3   Test 3
4   Test 4
```

So if i put ./index.php?id=1 this returns the result of id=2 and id=2 => id=3 and so on...
My question is how to fix it to return accurate result not +1. I tried with <= or => operators the result is correct, but then my links doesnt work.

Here is the script

```
<?php

    if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
    $id = (int)$_GET['id'];
}else
{
    $id = 0;
}

$stmt1 = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM records WHERE id > ? ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1");
$stmt1->bindValue(1,$id);
$stmt1->execute();
$row = $stmt1->fetch();

$stmt2 = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM records WHERE id < ? ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");

$stmt2->bindValue(1,$id);
$stmt2->execute();
$row = $stmt2->fetch();




echo $row['id'];
echo "<br/>";
echo $row['string'];

?>
```

Comment: Don't you want to have 2 as a next id to 1?  What's the problem with it?

Comment: if you put id=1 it return details for id=2 so id=0 return details for id=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if the problem as silly as that, but I have no other explanation.

To have your page you need to make 3 selects:

1. to get current page data
2. to get prev id
3. to get next one

But I can see only 2 selects

So, you have to select data for the very page to show

```
if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM records WHERE id = ?";
    $stm = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stm->execute(array($_GET['id']));
} else {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM records ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1";
    $stm = $db->query($sql);
}
$row = $stm->fetch();
```

and now you can go for getting prev and next ids

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM records WHERE id < ? LIMIT 1";
$stm = $db->prepare($sql);
$stm->execute(array($row['id']));
$prev = $stm->fetchColumn();

$sql = "SELECT id FROM records WHERE id > ? LIMIT 1";
$stm = $db->prepare($sql);
$stm->execute(array($row['id']));
$next = $stm->fetchColumn();
```

Answer (score -1):

> i am tryin to make it to return next and previus row

There is no such thing as "previous" or "next" row in a table. Without explicit ordering, tables must be considered as unordered *set* of rows. And you shouldn't rely on auto_increment field to be sequentially numbered. For example:

- because there was interleaved insert on the table,
- because the server is allowed to reuse auto_increment after row deletion.

---

You probably have to modify your table structure to add a sequence number:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (id in primary key not null auto_increment,
 sequence_number int unique,
 value char(40));
```

While inserting your data you might rely on something like that:

```
INSERT INTO tbl (sequence_number, value)
VALUES (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl, ?)
```

And the query for the "next" and "prev":

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE sequence_number = ?-1 OR sequence_number = ?+1 
ORDER BY sequence_number;
```

Comment: So i need query to select all records ? What do you mean?